# How should Symfony forms choice options be defined so then can be easily accessed in a twig template?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

There seems to be many possible ways to do this but none seem ideal.

## Array solution

Use the same strings for both the choice values and labels (array keys and values)

```
// ContactType.php
$builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'Male'   => 'Male', 
        'Female' => 'Female',
    ),
));
```

Now in a twig template on, for example, a confirmation page the choice can be output as follows:

```
// show.html.twig
{{ gender }}
```

**Pros:**

- Simple to implement
- Templates are simple to create and for designers to understand

**Cons:**

- If the submitted form's data is stored in a database the gender option will be stored as a full string `Male` or `Female` rather than a machine friendly value such as `'m'` or `'f'`, or `0` or `1`, which seems bad programming practice

## ChoiceList solution

Use machine friendly values for the choice options and create a Twig filter to read these in the template.

```
// GenderChoiceList.php
class GenderChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList 
{
    protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        $choices = array(
            0 => 'm', 
            1 => 'f',
        );

        $labels = array(
            0 => 'Male', 
            1 => 'Female',
        );

        return new ChoiceList($choices, $labels);
    }
}

// ContactType.php
$builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choice_list'  => new GenderChoiceList(),
));

// TwigExtension.php
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('getChoice', function ($value) {
    $genderChoiceList = new GenderChoiceList();
    $choices = $genderChoiceList->getChoicesForValues(array($value))
    return $choices[0];
});

// show.html.twig
{{ gender|getChoice }}
```

**Pros:**

- The gender is now stored in the database in a more sensible format

**Cons:**

- Lots more code for something that feels like it should be trivial
- Use of the Twig filter in the template is not clear and obvious for designers

## Doctrine solution

Create a related entity for the choice options.

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Gender.php

// ...
class Gender
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    // ...
}


// src/AppBundle/Entity/Contact.php

// ...
class Contact
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gender", inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gender_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $gender;
}

// ContactType.php
$builder->add('gender', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Gender',
));

// show.html.twig
{{ gender }} or {{ gender.name }}
```

**Pros:**

- The gender is stored in the database in a more sensible format
- The choices are also stored in the database, which seems like a sensible place for this kind of data
- The template code is simple and clear

**Cons:**

- There is a lot of code for something that feels like it should be trivial
- There will be additional database calls when rendering the template unless a custom query with joins is written, which is again more code

## Concluding question

Is there a better option? Something simple with no cons?

**UPDATE:**

Perhaps this can be handled best in the `Contact` entity's `getGender()` method.

```
// Contact.php
class Contact
{
    // ...

    public function getGender()
    {
        if (null === $this->gender) {
            return $this->gender;
        }

        $choices = array(
            'm' => 'Male',
            'f' => 'Female',
        );

        return $choices[$this->gender];
    }

    // ...
}
```

To output the full string `Male` or `Female` as follows:

```
// show.html.twig
{{ gender }}
```

Comment: Why don't just use `'choices'  => array(  'm'   => 'Male',  'f' => 'Female' )` ?

Comment: Then how would I output 'Female' or 'Male' on my confirmation page?

Comment: For something as simple as gender that won't change anytime soon I would go with the first option. I think you're worrying too much about details like machine readability that don't particularly matter in this case. It's simple and effective and as you said, easy to understand.

Comment: On the other hand, if you had a very long list of choices, the last option might make more sense. I don't think any of these examples is bad, it's just about picking the right approach for the data you're planning to store.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I agree that the choice of solution depends on the situation and also that storing some labels directly in the database isn't terribly bad. I used gender here as a simple short example. Other choice widgets aren't so simple but don't warrant the expense of storing in a DB table. It would be nice if there was a simple built in way to retrieve a submitted choice widget's labels in a template, such as a confirmation page or email. The ChoiceList/TwigExtension code I wrote above doesn't work and it's seems that ChoiceLists don't offer any methods for retrieving the choice labels!

Answer (score 0):

I use the ChoiceList/TwigExtension approach for a  couple of reasons:

- Generically speaking, an entity shouldn't have to know about display logic
- Centralizing retrieval logic in the TwigExtension means that it's easy to apply transformations to all your lists in the future

To make it easy to get at the choice values, define them so that they are accessible in the type:

```
class GenderChoiceList extends ChoiceList
{
    public $keyValues = ['m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(array_keys($this->keyValues), array_values($this->keyValues));
    }
}
```

Make your filter or function aware of the ChoiceList form which the values should be retrieved (I typically use a function):

```
class ChoiceTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('choice', array($this, 'choiceFunction'))
        ];
    }

    public function choiceFunction($class, $choice)
    {
        $choiceList = new $class;
        return $choiceList->keyValues[$choice];
    }
    ...
```

In the template, pass the class and the key for the label:

```
{{ choice('Bundle\\ChoiceList\\GenderChoiceList', gender) }}
```

So, similar to the way that Twig's `constant` works.

Speaking of constants, this can probably be made a bit cleaner now that PHP 5.6 supports array consts.

Aside: I like having all the lists as distinct ChoiceList classes.  This may seem like a bit of overkill at the beginning of a project, but makes life much easier as the system evolves and forms multiply.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. How do you get the labels `Male`, `Female` etc from the ChoiceList object? I've not been able to find a method that returns these. I thought `getChoicesForValues()` would but it returns `m` or `f`..

Comment: That's the ugly part.  Updated.